# iOS UITableView showing section header programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to show a section header programmatically. Here's what I have.

```
- (void)refreshSectionHeader
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

-

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self shouldShowSectionHeader]) {

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:15];
        label.text = @"It'sa me! Mario!";
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        return label;

    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self shouldShowSectionHeader]) {
        return 20;

    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It almost works. When I call `refreshSectionHeader`, the header appears correctly but no text is displayed (the label). As soon as I scroll the tableView, the text appears. Obviously, I want the text to appear right away. Any ideas how to solve this?

Also, the header disappear correctly when `shouldShowSectionHeader` returns `NO`.

Comment: You say you want a table view header but you have implemented two methods related to section headers. Which header do you really mean?

Comment: My bad, I want a section header. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found 3 ways to solve this problem. Here they are.

You do not have to implement all three. Only 1 of these 3 will suffice.

Solution 1 is the best imo.

---

1 - In `viewForHeaderInSection`, make sure you init the label with the proper frame. Also, add it to a UIView. Return that UIView instead of the UILabel.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self shouldShowSectionHeader]) {

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:15];
        label.text = @"All your base are belong to us!";
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        UIView *sectionHeader = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [sectionHeader addSubview:label];

        return sectionHeader;

    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

---

2 - Use

```
- (void)refreshSectionHeader
{
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Instead of

```
- (void)refreshSectionHeader
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

---

3 - Scroll the tableview programmatically like so

```
- (void)refreshTableViewHeader
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    CGPoint contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.y++;
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:NO];
    contentOffset.y--;
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:NO];    

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a custom setter for `shouldShowTableViewHeader`

```
-(void)setShouldShowTableViewHeader:(BOOL)shouldShow
{
    _shouldShowTableViewHeader = shouldShow;
    [self refreshTableViewHeader];
}
```

---

please try to give a size to your label upfront

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:15];
label.text = @"It'sa me! Mario!";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[label sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Good idea, but it is not related to the issue. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: The issue is not that the methods aren't called properly. They are all successfully called. The issue is that the UILabel is not correctly displayed after the header has appeared. The label text only appears after the tableview is subsequently scrolled.

Comment: Let me try that, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't matter. I use a footer which I do not `initWithFrame` and it works perfectly.

Comment: I didn't think about `[label sizeToFit];`. I just tried it and it changes nothing.

Comment: do u set another header in the storyboard?

Comment: Yeah, I use another header in the second section, which is empty. That header acts as a footer for the first section. I also use a real tableView footer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `[self.tableView reloadData]` instead of

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: That works :) the section header appears and the label text is displayed correctly. But the whole thing is not animated, which is problematic.